# Mirroring during retopology creates aberrations on mirrored axis

Tags: sculpting, mirror, topology

No idea how else to explain than to show this:

It should be mirroring it, but for some reason the other side comes out really weird. And not just this part. There are other parts, too.

**Side A with mesh off:**
[image]

**Side B with mess off:**
[image]

**Side A with mesh on:**
[image]

**Side B with mesh on:**
[image]

**Even the back is messed up, where it is supposed to be symmetrical (note that the right side is the mirrored part):**
[image]

**For comparison reasons, here's the matcap version of the rear as shown above. It's symmetrical, as you can see, because it was done symmetrically when sculpted:**
[image]

**Out of interest in rearranging modifiers, moving the shrinkwrap modifier before the mirror and hiding the mesh makes the holes disappear that would otherwise be there, but the mirroring is messed up if mesh is enabled in that the "keep above surface" on the mirrored side doesn't work:**
[image]

Again, it *should* not happen, but it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I noticed something: if I remove mirror modifier from the modifier queue, and reapply it so that it goes to the end instead of being the first modifier, the whole thing shrinks, but no aberrations in the plane-based retopo mesh happen when everything is applied (no holes or weird topology problems occur--although the mesh is slightly smaller and an inverse relationship happens where the original mesh now sticks out a lot more vs the new one). Is this a Blender bug?

Comment: Another update: I tried putting an object at [0,0,0] and have that serve as the object axis on which to mirror. But it ends up being a problem; even if I move the object as the pivot point for the mirror, something is still wrong with the mirrored side.

Comment: hard to understand, could you please share your file or at least the part with the problem? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: try to remirror your rabbit with the dyntopo Symmetrize button, you'll see that you'll see holes both sides. But what is your final goal with this shrinkwrap? I don't think you could avoid holes, except with a big offset or with some manual corrections. And even if you have holes, what's the problem? I guess you're not supposed to keep both the 2 objects...

Comment: It's probably a symmetry problem as you said because I found out that doing a "Bool Mesh Symm Function" on the ears fixes this. It also means I need to re-topologize a lot of the parts but at least it works now. I should have used this before actually doing retopology. Argh. Thanks for your help, btw. The idea is to reduce poly count, and shrinkwrap helps keep the planes on top of the surface. It's absolutely necessary. Now all I need to do is simply "grab" the pieces that aren't falling into place and they automatically go on top of the new symmetry. Easy fix.

Comment: Yes I understand the retopology, but once you've done it you can get rid of the high-poly version, so maybe the holes are not so important

Comment: Right. That's the plan. I just need to clean it up and then it'll be fine. I just wanted to know why it was so strange. Now I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your high-poly object is not really symmetrical, try to remirror your rabbit with the dyntopo *Symmetrize* button, you'll see holes both sides.

Comment: Thank you for your help, @moonboots, you've solved my issue with symmetry. I also wanted to add that symmetry with the ears in particular was fixed by doing that without having to re-do everything. That was the only problem (I thought I had copy-and-pasted the ears right, but apparently I didn't).